# The directory name and file name meaning of tiled files and in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, tiles, geowebcache

In GeoServer, after I seed/truncate one layer(such as predefined "topp:states"),

[image]

when I look into the tiled files, for example zoom level 5, the directory **EPSG_900913_05** (which is the zoom level directory) has two subdirectories **1_2** and **0_2**, and in each subdirectory has files such like 10_21.png, 10_19.png, 09_19.png, ...

I want to know the meaning of the subdirectory name and file name, or in other words: what's the rule for generating these subdirectory names and file names?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The directory structure of the file-based tile cache of GeoWebCache is defined in the source code. I suppose that it is here https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/tree/main/geowebcache/core/src/main/java/org/geowebcache/storage/blobstore/file.

The layout is described in GeoServer documentation https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/blobstores.html

> GeoWebCache default uses a path structure reducing the number of items
> in each directory, by splitting long lists in groups. In particular,
> the layout is z/xc_yc/x_y.ext where xc=x/(2^(z/2)), yc=y/(2^(z/2)). In
> other words, the tiles are split into square areas, the number of
> square areas growing with the zoom level, and each square being
> assigned to a intermediate directory. The Y coordinates are numbered
> from the south northwards.

Users are not supposed to read the tiles straight from the GeoWebCache storage. The directory structure does not follow the z/y/x pattern of TMS or WMTS services because that would lead into directories with very many files and potentially troubles with file systems having too few inodes. However, there are other tiling software that do use the z/x/y pattern and I do not know how reasonable the design decision was. At least it has made it impossible to publish cached tiles by simply copying the tile directory from GeoWebCache into any http server.

**EDIT** Since late 2019 it has been possible to configure the blobstore to follow either the TMS or XYZ (slippy) structure.

https://sourceforge.net/p/geowebcache/mailman/message/36794065/

Users who are using the integrated GeoWebCache through GeoServer can't change the directory layout of the default blobstore into TMS or XYZ. However, they can create a new blobstore and configure that to use an alternative layout as documented in https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/blobstores.html.

Comment: That is unless you change the blobstore layout to TMS or XYZ - https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/blobstores.html#file-blobstore

Comment: Thank you, I did not know or remember that.

Comment: the `xc=x/(2^(z/2))`, `yc=y/(2^(z/2))` formula in quoted GeoServer documentation above is wrong? I check out [DefaultFilePathGenerator.java](https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/blob/main/geowebcache/core/src/main/java/org/geowebcache/storage/blobstore/file/DefaultFilePathGenerator.java) and found that the denominator is not `2^` but `2<<shift`(where shift is `z/2`), right? @user30184

Comment: Sorry, I have never seen that formula before today. What I can say is that because GeoWebCache works well with that directory layout then it must be right. If something does not match then it is the literal description.

Comment: A bit shift is equivalent to multiplication by a power of 2... https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Computer_Science/Programming_Languages/Book%3A_Deep_into_Pharo_(Bergel_Cassou_Ducasse_and_Laval)/14%3A_Exploring_Little_Numbers/14.02%3A_Bit_Shifting_Is_Multiplying_by_2_Powers